# Как избавиться от ошибки 500 при установке плагина кеширования?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, .htaccess, веб-сервер

Устанавливаю плагин для кеширования w3 total cache или WP Super Cache. При установке на open server всё работает нормально, при установке на хостинг получаю ответ 500 от сервера.

C w3 total cache успеваю только активировать, сразу всё падает, приходится через ftp удалять. С WP Super Cache работает админка и сайт, пока я в админке, но после выхода опять получаю 500.

Пока искал ответ просмотрел debug.php, там ошибка, которая на локальном сервере не возникает:

PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in /home/my_site/public_html/wp-includes/cache.php on line 123

В чём может быть проблема и как это можно исправить?

Comment: У вас что-то напутано с объектным кешем. При попытке обращения к нему сайт падает. Удалите все другие плагины объектного кеширования, вроде Redis или Memcached. Возможно, придётся переустановить ядро WP, W3TC и Wp Super Cache.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Переносил сайт с помощью All-in-One WP Migration, единственная разница между сайтами - протокол и плагин для перехода на https (Really Simple SSL). Как что-то могло спутаться, если я не вносил изменений? Вышеупомянутые плагины для объектного кеширования не использовал.

Comment: Без отладчика в руках понять, что произошло, очень трудно. Я вам называю причину падения. В строке 123 идёт попытка чтения из объектного кеша. Если вы не ставили другие плагины объектного кеширования, то объектный кеш может создаётся ядром WP, а потом подменяется плагином W3TC. Неправильная установка плагина W3TC способна привести к такому результату, потому что он размещает некоторые свои файлы в папках ядра. Возможно, вы не все файлы скопировали. Ещё раз: 1) переустановите ядро, 2) удалите и переустановите плагины W3TC и Super Cache. И да, одновременно их активировать нельзя.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, И я перенёс актуальную версию с хостинга обратно на open server, на локальном снова всё работает.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Одновременно я не устанавливал, просто проверял, как работают другие плагины. Спасибо за наводку, буду пробовать ваши варианты и разбираться дальше.